# Como igualar um vetor vindo de uma matriz com uma matriz na função principal?

Tags: c

Preciso igualar uma matriz que está retornando de uma função a uma matriz na função principal. Meu objetivo com isso é poder passar essa mesma matriz como parâmetro para outras funções sem precisar ficar chamando a função na hora de enviar a matriz.

Exemplo:

```
// função para retirar os espaços digitados
int retira_espaco(int tamanho, char vetor[], int t, char retorno []){ 
    int i = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for (i=0; i<tamanho && vetor[i] != 0; i++){ //Nesse 'for' tem que se verificar se  vetor[i] !=0 pois o fgets sempre adiciona um 0 binario no final do que foi digitado
        if (isdigit(vetor[i]) || vetor[i] == 'i' || vetor[i] == 'p'
       || vetor[i] == '+' || vetor[i] == '-' || vetor[i] == '*'
       || vetor[i] == '/' || vetor[i] == '^' || vetor[i] == '='){
            retorno[contador++] = vetor[i];
        }
    }
    retorno[contador] = '\0';
    return (retorno);
}
```

Na hora de enviar os parâmetros para essa primeira função tenho que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
int main(){    
    printf("%s\n", retira_espaco(tamanho, vetor, tamanho, retorno));
}
```

Quero então igualar uma matriz na função principal a matriz que retorna do retira_espaço, como proceder?

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Não entendi a sua dúvida. O que significa "igualar uma matriz"? Igualar a que? Também não entendi o que a sua função deveria fazer (o retorno de um valor inteiro com o índice de onde supostamente há um `+` ou um `-`, que não é uma matriz, não tem nada a ver com o que o nome da função diz que ela faz).

Comment: Perdão,amigo, inseri uma função diferente e não tinha percebido, agora concertei.
O que eu quero igualar é a matriz retorno com uma matriz na função principal. Normalmente para igualar matrizes se usa
     for ( i = 0; i<10; i++){
           matriz[i] = retorno[i];
     }
só que como não sei como fazer isso quando a matriz retorno, como no caso, está vindo de uma função.

Comment: Eu retirei o voto pra fechar. Mas ainda assim, não está totalmente claro. Vc quer comparar o conteúdo de `retorno`, *após a chamada de `retira_espaco`*, com alguma outra matriz, é isso? Esse exemplo que você postou não compara, e sim atribui. O `=` único é diferente do `==` duplo de comparação.

Comment: Exato, porque assim eu consigo utilizar a matriz retorno dentro da função principal sem precisar ficar chamando ela toda hora.

Comment: @Miguel Goffredo, o que você quer eu já entendi. Basicamente, quer alterar a matriz (vetor por ter tamanho 1 em umas das dimensões) que passou para a função. Quer que a matriz que passou seja alterada para ter o novo conteúdo retornado. Editei sua pergunta para melhorar o texto, deixar com o visual mais convidativo, arrumar erros e adicionar "*tags*" que serão pertinentes. Já estou para responder a ti.

Comment: @José não editaste nada ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. eu editei mas como tiverem duas pessoas com edição aguardando aprovação do mesmo conteúdo (você, no caso), o que eu editei se perdeu.

Comment: @José mas tem de estar no histórico mesmo assim, e eu não vejo nada. Estranho...

Comment: @JorgeB. é verdade; não está no histórico! E eu havia editado a resposta para facilitar o entendimento! Mas basicamente o colega quer alterar a matriz original com o que foi feito na função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está querendo fazer é atribuir o array `retorno` que foi preenchido pela função `retira_espaco` para um outro array, mas isto é desnecessário, porque os arrays são passados por "referência" quando são usados como parâmetros de funções. Isto é, o array `retorno` dentro da função `retira_espaco` é o mesmo array de fora da função que foi passado como parâmetro.

Exemplificando

```
char x[100], y[100];

// ...outros comandos

// o array "retorno" dentro de retira_espaco na verdade e' o array y aqui de fora
retira_espaco(100, x, 100, y);

printf("%s", y);
```

Agora, sua função `retira_espaco` está erradamente declarada como `int retira_espaco`, deveria ser `void retira_espaco`. Além disso não está usando o 3º parâmetro `t`, e aquele comando final `return (retorno)` é desnecessário e na verdade errado, só faria sentido se o tipo da função fosse `char *`.

Além disso, seu exemplo `printf("%s\n", retira_espaco(tamanho, vetor, tamanho, retorno));`está errado, pois o formato `%s` é para strings (char*), e você declarou a função `retira_espaco` como int.

Answer (score 2):

## Vejamos...

A melhor forma de lidar com seu problema é usar a idéia de **passagem por referência** dos argumentos. E isso cai naquela nuvem negra de ponteiros - mas que é fácil depois que domina!

Se quiser ler sobre ponteiros, eu indico [este material da USP](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html). É curto, conciso e fácil de entender. Também indico [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106957/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-c) do Stack Overflow em inglês se dominar o idioma.

## Solucionando o problema

Tomando como verdade o código que você forneceu e deixando-o enxuto para o propósito de exemplificação, o que poderia ser feito é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void retira_espaco( char * vetor ){

  int i, j, tamanho;

  tamanho = strlen( vetor );

  for ( i = 0; ( i < tamanho ) && ( vetor[i] != 0 ); i++ ){

    if( isdigit( vetor[i] ) || vetor[i] == 'i' || vetor[i] == 'p' || vetor[i] == '+' || vetor[i] == '-' || vetor[i] == '*' || vetor[i] == '/' || vetor[i] == '^' || vetor[i] == '=') {

      /* Movimenta para posteriores posições para dentro, eliminando caracteres desejados */
      for( j = i; j < (tamanho - 1); j++ ) vetor[j] = vetor[j+1];
      vetor[ tamanho - 1 ] = '\0';

      /* Por conta do movimento acima, precisa-se checar a posição atual novamente */
      --i;

    }

  }

}

int main( void ){

  char vetor[] = "abcdef+=efghijklmnopq/xyz";

  retira_espaco( vetor );

  printf( "Resultado: %s\n", vetor );

  return( 0 );

}
```

O resultado obtido é satisfatório:

```
Resultado: abcdefefghjklmnoqxyz
```

## Explicando

Se você cria um ponteiro - imagino que saiba o que é um ponteiro ou que leu o artigo recomendado - como parâmetro para a função (exemplo: `char * vetor`), você poderá passar sua matriz `vetor` como referência para a função - ou seja, não passasse o valor e sim o endereço de memória do mesmo. Isso significa que poderá modificar o conteúdo da matriz original.

O que aqui foi feito é simples:

- criou-se a função que modifica a matriz: `void retira_espaco( char * vetor ){...}`
- passou-se, por referência, uma matriz pré-determinada para ser modificada: `retira_espaco( vetor );`
- verificou-se se a modificação ocorreu: `printf( "Resultado: %s\n", vetor );`

Note que vetores passamos por referência por padrão. Se fosse um vetor alocado, usaríamos o operador `&` para referênciar. Exemplo:

- a função ficaria: `void retira_espaco( char ** vetor ){...}`
- a declaração da matriz em `main()` ficaria: `char **vetor = malloc(...);`
- a passagem por referência ficaria: `retira_espaco( &vetor );`

Desta forma, poder-se-ia não só manter os valores bem como também modificar o tamanho de memória alocada. Com alocação dinâmica de memória, ao invés de preencher com '\0', se obteria uma matriz de tamanho apropriado e com menor consumo de memória. Porém, é um pouco mais trabalhoso e foge ao escopo de apresentação do tema.